# How do I create an email address with multiple recipients in heroku?

Tags: email, heroku

I want to setup an email alias eg. dev@mycompany.com and have multiple recipients to that. My company's site is hosted in a heroku instance and I want to leverage the same instance for the email forwarding. Can someone please explain how this works and how I can set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will only provide you with hosting for your web application. You need to use another service for your emails, like [Google Apps](https://apps.google.com/).

If you already have email addresses for your domain name, you probably also already have a service providing this. You need to figure out which it is and configure it there.

Comment: I don't have email addresses yet. Google Apps gives me whole email capability and it's not free. I could use the add-ons heroku provides for email but I don't need to send/receive emails using the company address. I just need those email addresses to forward to some other email address. eg. Sending email to me@mycompany.com should forward to me@gmail.com and we@mycompany.com should forward to [a@example.com, b@example.com, c@example.com].

Comment: You need to use an external service. Heroku doesn't offer this.